# Can this query be written with out using variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can this query be written with out using variable?

Basically what I need is an ID of some thing from some table for inserting a new record. Right now I'm doing it by storing that ID in variable and then using it.

```
DECLARE @store_num char(4);
SELECT  @store_num = [store_no] FROM store WHERE (store_name = 'Rocky Mountain Produce');
INSERT INTO [ITD640_B].[dbo].[employee]
           ([employee_no]
           ,[employee_fname]
           ,[employee_lname]
           ,[store_no])
     VALUES
           (123456
           ,'YourFirstName'
           ,'YourLastName'
           ,@store_num);
```

Comment: please don't use "[" and "]" unless they are necessary (in the above code, they are not necessary), they make the code a pain to read!!!  this will greatly help the poor sap maintaining your code 5 years from now!

Comment: @KM: These were generated by `SQL Server Manager Studio` not me. But thanks for the helpful tip. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [ITD640_B].[dbo].[employee]
     ([employee_no]
     ,[employee_fname]
     ,[employee_lname]
     ,[store_no])
SELECT 
     123456
     ,'YourFirstName'
     ,'YourLastName'
     ,[store_no]
FROM 
     store 
WHERE 
     store_name = 'Rocky Mountain Produce';
```

Comment: +1: Beat me by 51 seconds.  But the brackets in the WHERE are unnecessary.

Comment: Minor detail: Missing a comma between 'YourLastName' and [store_no]

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [ITD640_B].[dbo].[employee]
           ([employee_no]
           ,[employee_fname]
           ,[employee_lname]
           ,[store_no])
     SELECT
           123456
           ,'YourFirstName'
           ,'YourLastName'
           ,[store_no]
        FROM store
        WHERE store_name = 'Rocky Mountain Produce'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method using a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO [ITD640_B].[dbo].[employee]
           ([employee_no]
           ,[employee_fname]
           ,[employee_lname]
           ,[store_no])
     VALUES
           (123456
           ,'YourFirstName'
           ,'YourLastName'
           ,(SELECT [store_no] FROM store WHERE (store_name = 'Rocky Mountain Produce')))
```